# Adopt authorities from JWT in Spring Resource Server

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2

My Spring OAuth2 client only grants the *ROLE_USER* authority to authenticated users, ignoring the authorities from `resource_access` in the provided JWT.

```
{
"wdb": {
  "roles": [
    "TestRole",
    "TestRoleFoo",
    "TestRoleBar"
  ]
}
```

How can I setup my OAuth2 client to also grant the authorities from `resource_access` (*TestRole*, *TestRoleFoo*, *TestRoleBar*)? Am I missing some crucial configuration here?

#### My configuration in detail

On my Resource Server, I'm using Springs default OAuth2 client with the following configuration:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: wdb
      client-secret: some-secret
      access-token-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
      user-authorization-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth
      scope: openid profile email
      authorized-grant-types: code
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
```

My Keycloak Authorization Server provides me with the following JWT payload:

```
{
  "jti": "6a666808-2b69-4de0-ab94-9ceebdac13de",
  "exp": 1569674641,
  "nbf": 0,
  "iat": 1569674341,
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "f19b0443-4cce-495a-8479-ff36f82628fc",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "wdb",
  "auth_time": 1569674341,
  "session_state": "0a411eda-0efb-4f29-99c4-b54da6298d6c",
  "acr": "1",
  "allowed-origins": [
    "/*"
  ],
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "wdb": {
      "roles": [
        "TestRole",
        "TestRoleFoo",
        "TestRoleBar"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "email_verified": true,
  "user_name": "sullrich",
  "name": "Sebastian Ullrich",
  "preferred_username": "sullrich",
  "given_name": "Sebastian",
  "locale": "de",
  "family_name": "Ullrich",
  "email": "sebastian@wdb.local"
}
```

Within my Resource Server, this JWT will be derived to the following `OAuth2Authentication`:

```
{
   "authorities":[
      {
         "authority":"ROLE_USER"
      }
   ],
   "details":{
      "remoteAddress":"0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
      "sessionId":"... session id ...",
      "tokenValue":"... encoded payload ...",
      "tokenType":"bearer"
   },
   "authenticated":true,
   "userAuthentication":{
      "authorities":[
         {
            "authority":"ROLE_USER"
         }
      ],
      "details":{
         "sub":"f19b0443-4cce-495a-8479-ff36f82628fc",
         "email_verified":true,
         "user_name":"sullrich",
         "name":"Sebastian Ullrich",
         "preferred_username":"sullrich",
         "given_name":"Sebastian",
         "locale":"de",
         "family_name":"Ullrich",
         "email":"sebastian@wdb.local"
      },
      "authenticated":true,
      "principal":"Sebastian Ullrich",
      "credentials":"N/A",
      "name":"Sebastian Ullrich"
   },
   "principal":"Sebastian Ullrich",
   "credentials":"",
   "clientOnly":false,
   "oauth2Request":{
      "clientId":"wdb",
      "scope":[

      ],
      "requestParameters":{

      },
      "resourceIds":[

      ],
      "authorities":[

      ],
      "approved":true,
      "refresh":false,
      "responseTypes":[

      ],
      "extensions":{

      }
   },
   "name":"Sebastian Ullrich"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you need a custom JwtAuthenticationConverter
Spring will only map scopes into granted authorities by default.

You can create a class that extends the default implementation and overrides the extractAuthorities method.
Then you have access to the claims and you can map them to the roles you want.

```
public class JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter extends JwtAuthenticationConverter { 


    @Override 
    protected Collection<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Jwt jwt) { 
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities =  super.extractAuthorities(jwt); 
        if(jwt.containsClaim("roles") && jwt.getClaimAsStringList("roles").contains("TestRole")) { 
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_TestRole")); 
        } else { 
            .........
        } 
        return authorities; 
    }
```

Then you plug in your version into the resource server in your WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter:

```
@Override 
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
        http.
......
            .oauth2ResourceServer() 
                .jwt() 
                    .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter());
```

Your roles are a bit more nested i.e. under resource_access . wdb 
You can always create a keycloak mapper to add them under roles in the parent node to simplify things.

Here is an example of a resource server that does something similar
https://github.com/wlesniak/effective-oauth2-with-spring-security-and-spring-boot/tree/master/module_8/mod8_support-service

Comment: "You can always create a keycloak mapper to add them under roles in the parent node to simplify things." This pointed me into the right direction :) Thanks